# Save image to sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql, image

I am currently trying to write an image to a database, but the articles i have seen and tried are lines and lines of code; which in the end do not work.

I was just wondering if anyone knows of any articles; or if anyone can point me in the correct direction.

Thanks!

By the way i am using asp.net 4.0; and am trying to write to an sql database.

Comment: Can you explain some of the things you have tried? What hasn't worked for you?

Comment: And why not save images in the file system, and only their path on the database? RDBMSs are not a good option for binary data IMHO.

Comment: I have been trying for an hour or so, i have tried saving to a databyte array but that did not work. I have nearly got it working but it comes up with the error (The directive 'webhandler' is unknown) when i try to add this to the top of the aspx page: <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ShowImage" %>

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the image to binary format, after that you can save it to your data base.

If you are using sql server i found this article (he is good):

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020929.asp

http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/

Very short example:

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 bool staus = _usersLogic.saveUserPicture(userID, ms.ToArray());
```

In this line:

```
bool staus = _usersLogic.saveUserPicture(userID, ms.ToArray());
```

I am sending a `UserID` and the image as `binary` format to function in a repository which responsible of saving the user picture to my database

this `ms.ToArray()` is what you need to save in the database

And when you want to get the picture back from your database you should use:

```
imgUser.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(_user.Picture);
```

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look at that when i get the chance!

Answer (score 0):

This ASPSnippets article addresses saving a webpage file upload to SQL (using MP3s, but same concept for any file):

[Save MP3 Audio Files to database and display in ASP.Net GridView with Play and Download option](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-MP3-Audio-Files-to-database-and-display-in-ASPNet-GridView-with-Play-and-Download-option.aspx)

has multiple screenshots/code snippets in the article

Comment: Thanks, i will have a gander at that